# Number Format in React Native

Tags: react-native, native-base

It might be a silly question, but I haven't found a solution for it. How can I format my native base input to accept only numbers and format it as dollar format?

```
import { Input } from 'native-base';
...
onChangeText = (text, input) => {
    const obj = { ...this.state.myData };

    obj[input] = text;

    this.setState({
      myData: obj
    });
};
...

const { Total } = this.state.myData;
...
<Input
    value={Total}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text, 'Total')}
    style={styles.valueText}
/>
```

It is working, but how can I change to accept only numbers and format with dollar sign?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In documentation:

> *Props provide configurability for several features, such as auto-correction, auto-capitalization, placeholder text, and different
>   keyboard types, such as a numeric keypad.*

Try this.

```
<Input
value={Total}
onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text, 'Total')}
style={styles.valueText} 
keyboardType="number-pad"
/>
```

On IOS try keyboardType="numbers-and-punctuation".

Answer (score 1):

add keyboardType="number-pad" + on your this.onChangeText function test your number by regular expression of currency format and apply format manually if it's not correct.

If you want there's a library which will do it for you https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format but in this case, you'll need to add styles to make it look like your input from native-base

Comment: Do you have an example of this real-number-format. It did not work for me. Also, using keyboardType="number-pad", I still can type letters in the IOS simulator

Comment: You can modify your function and by regexp allow only numbers

Comment: Do you have an example?